# getElementsByClassName not working

Tags: javascript, webforms, html-table, dynamic-data

I coded a php page that displays information from a mysql database neatly into tables. I would like to hide empty table rows with an onLoad event handler.

Here is a sample table with code that hides a `<td>` when it has no content. but i can only get it to work with different IDs:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function hideTd(id){
            if(document.getElementById(id).textContent == ''){
              document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            }
          }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="hideTd('1');hideTd('2');hideTd('3');">
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td id="1">not empty</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="2"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="3"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

what i want to do is use a class for the `<td>`s to achieve the same thing while only referencing the class once, and not referencing every single id that I want to remove, which will not even work for my dynamic content. I tried using this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function hideTd(){
        if(document.getElementsByClassName().textContent == ''){
          document.getElementsByClassName().style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="hideTd('1');">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td class="1">not empty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="1"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

but it does not work. its supposed to hide the empty `<td>`s that have the specified class. how do i hide empty `<td>`s using classes, not IDs?

Comment: I've posted an answer with a function that works as a fallback if getElementsByClassName doesn't exist

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. Class names (and IDs) are [not allowed to start with a digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names).
2. You have to pass a class to `getElementsByClassName()`.
3. You have to iterate of the result set.

Example (*untested*):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideTd(className){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
       if( elements[i].textContent == ''){
          elements[i].style.display = 'none';
       } 
    }

  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="hideTd('td');">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="td">not empty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Note that `getElementsByClassName()` [is not available up to and including IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements).

**Update:**

Alternatively you can give the table an ID and use:

```
var elements = document.getElementById('tableID').getElementsByTagName('td');
```

to get all `td` elements.

To hide the parent row, use the `parentNode` property of the element:

```
elements[i].parentNode.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: it's working now! but if getElementsByClassName() is not available in IE, is there an alternative way to hide an empty td without referencing each one? Also, is there a way to hide the whole tr if the td is empty? Thanks

Comment: @new star: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Update:  getElementsByClassName() works in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it by ClassName you could do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideTd(className){
    var elements;

    if (document.getElementsByClassName)
    {
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    }
    else
    {
        var elArray = [];
        var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName(elements);  
        var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className+ "(\\s|$)");
        for ( var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++ ) {

            if ( regex.test(tmp[i].className) ) {
                elArray.push(tmp[i]);
            }
        }

        elements = elArray;
    }

    for(var i = 0, i < elements.length; i++) {
       if( elements[i].textContent == ''){
          elements[i].style.display = 'none';
       } 
    }

  }
</script>
```