# Javascript only affects one element

Tags: javascript, css

*I don't understand, the border is only visible on the first item, why?*

**HTML**

```
<div id="theContainer">
    <div id="item">Content 1</div>
    <div id="item">Content 2</div>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('item').style.borderTop = '1px solid #0ea2c7';​
```

JsFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SbNKa/52/)

Comment: `id` is supposed to be unique within the document. You may want to use class instead.

Comment: Are you sure about javascript support borderTop method of css ?

Comment: well, why don't you use this in a css property like this one http://jsfiddle.net/SbNKa/53/ ! no need of js!

Comment: It's likely that there are better approaches to what you are trying to do than style elements explicitly using script. One obvious one is to define a class with the `border-top: 1px solid #0ea2c7` property and add that class to the elements. Better yet, make a CSS declaration such as `#theContainer.border-items .item { border-top: 1px solid #0ea2c7; }` and then you'll  just need to add the `border-items` class to the single `#theContainer` element.

Comment: Hope this may work :

[reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349332/getelementsbyclassname-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName`

**JavaScript**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for (i =0; i < ele.length; i++)    {
    elements[i].style.borderTop = '1px solid #000';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="theContainer">
    <div class="item">Content 1</div>
    <div class="item">Content 2</div>
</div>​
```

​
**CSS**

```
#theContainer {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #900;
    padding: 10px;
}
.item {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
​
```

Answer (score -1):

"**document.getElementById**" means "Returns a reference to the element by its ID", see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById); and id means identity, you should have only one element in your dom tree per id.

If you want to style multiple elements, try to use class.

**HTML**

```
<div id="theContainer">
    <div class="item">Content 1</div>
    <div class="item">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item { border-top: 1px solid #0ea2c7; }
```